# Unable to update Stack Overflow profile information. Getting email address is already registered error

Tags: bug, profile-page, accounts

When trying to update the Profile info under *Edit Profile & Settings* I get an error. It is not related to any specific field being updated as I get it making any change to my profile.

I am not changing my email address and I have no problem logging in. For good measure, I went ahead and did change my password and logged in with the new password and the same thing happens. I get the following error message.

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile: This email address is
>   already registered. If it belongs to you, log in above or visit our
>   account recovery page to get access to this account.

Also worth mentioning that it is annoying that there is no way to report a bug short of creating this question.

Comment: You can use the Contact Us link at the bottom of the page also, although it is preferred you use this method.